# View Stub(Pagination) and Lazy loading of Images in android

Tags: android, listview, image, pagination, viewstub

In android mobile we have an default application Market, under submenu there is functionality called all applications. In this, first it shows only ten records in which it will display defalut image and text, then in back ground it will update images. When we scroll down (i.e., end of list) and it shows loading and then it loads next 10, images will load lazily.

How to acheive this senario.

Thanks in Adavance

Jayanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this, first it shows only ten
>   records in which it will display
>   defalut image and text, then in back
>   ground it will update images.

I have done this with my [`ThumbnailAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-thumbnail), though I want to rewrite it sometime in the next few months.

> When we scroll down (i.e., end of
>   list) and it shows loading and then it
>   loads next 10, images will load
>   lazily.

I have done this with my [`EndlessAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless).

Perhaps these will give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the samples. I will be using it with req. and will check it feasibility.

Comment: Hey, What exactly happens in the AdapterWrapper jar file. So that I can customize according to my req. where in each items it contains an image and text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "What exactly happens in the AdapterWrapper jar file" -- it is just an implementation of Adapter, designed to help people implement the decorator pattern.

Comment: I have gone through your code, can I use your class for customize list items like it contains an image and text. Is your Adapter wrapper class dependant to array adapter itself or can we use it to custom class adapters which extends base adapter.

 Thanks in advance.

Comment: `AdapterWrapper` should work with any adapter. `EndlessAdapter` has only been tried with `ArrayAdapter` and therefore may have issues with other adapter types. I need to revisit this code someday and try out more combinations.